# Replacing div content on the fly with a js function

Tags: javascript, html

OK so at the bottom of my function it should be updating my div to tell the user what their BMI is.

Here is the function where I am attempting to do this.

```
    function calcbmi(){

    //window.alert("hello");

    var weightvalue = document.getElementsByName('weight_pounds')[0].value;
    var weight = parseInt(weightvalue, 10)*0.453592;
    var height1value = document.getElementsByName('height_feet')[0].value;
    var height1 = parseInt(height1value, 10)*12;    
    var height2value = document.getElementsByName('height_inches')[0].value;
    var height2 = parseInt(height2value, 10);

    var height = (height1+height2) * 0.0254;

    //window.alert("Meters:" + height + "KG:" + weight);

    var bmi = Math.floor((weight/(height*height))); 

    //window.alert("your BMI is: " + bmi);

    var bmi = Math.floor((weight/(height*height))); 

    var container = document.getElementById("bmiinfo");
    container.innerHTML = bmi;


}
```

Here is the corresponding HTML...

```
  <td colspan="2"><div style="float:left;"><button onclick="calcbmi()">Calculate BMI</button></div> <div style="float:right;"><span class="hidemobile"></span>.</div><div style="clear:both;"></div></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        </form> 
    </div>
    <div id="userbmi">
        <h1>BMI is: <span id="bmi"></spam></h1>
    </div>
```

Am I missing something? This does not work.

@EDIT: no errors in console...

Comment: what is `weight` and `heigth` vaules?

Comment: Where are height and weight values coming from?

Comment: I will just include the whole function. The rest is actually working just fine as I can tell from a window.alert.

Comment: check if weight and height is correct and also since you are putting entire value inside innerHTML, it will replace your `<h1>BMI is: </h1>`

Comment: Just realized that ^ however I can easily fix that once I have gotten the change to actually work

Comment: Where and how are you calling your `calcbmi()` function?

Comment: Please post your form markup as well

Comment: @MadaraUchiha with an onclick()

Answer (score 4):

**Update**: (after looking into the webpage)

Replace `<button onclick="calcbmi()">Calculate BMI</button>`

to `<input onclick="calcbmi()" type="button" value="Calculate BMI"></input>`

Reason is that button tag defaults to form submission, so calcbmi is called but the page is refreshed instantaneously that it's un-noticable.

*Previous Answer*:

Modify your html like the following, and add a span, and then write the value to it.

```
<h1>BMI is: <span id="bmi"></span></h1>
```

Here's a working snippet

```js
function calcbmi (){
    var weightvalue = document.getElementsByName('weight_pounds')[0].value;
    var weight = parseInt(weightvalue, 10)*0.453592;
    var height1value = document.getElementsByName('height_feet')[0].value;
    var height1 = parseInt(height1value, 10)*12;    
    var height2value = document.getElementsByName('height_inches')[0].value;
    var height2 = parseInt(height2value, 10);

    var height = (height1+height2) * 0.0254;

    var bmi = Math.floor((weight/(height*height))); 

    var bmi = Math.floor((weight/(height*height))); 

    var container = document.getElementById("bmi");
    container.innerHTML = bmi;

}
```

```html
<div>
  Weight: <input type="text" name="weight_pounds" value=""><br/>
  Height (ft): <input type="text" name="height_feet" value=""><br/>
  Height (in): <input type="text" name="height_inches" value=""><br/>
</div>

<input type="button" onclick="calcbmi()" value="Calculate" />

<div id="bmiinfo">
  <h1>BMI is: <span id="bmi"></span></h1>
</div>
```

Comment: then please provide more details, as this works fine with you provided details

Comment: You may go to my website if you like and look in the console yourself I suppose. I have updated the code you changed here with the <span> attribute. Here is my url http://turing.cs.olemiss.edu/~jpcostan/rdnsim/rdnSimulator.html

Comment: @AmmarHasan Thank you so much! I was not aware that this would not work with <button>!!!